# Find and replace a string using another list of string in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, replace, find

I have a text

```
original = '3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 US NC'
```

I need to find US and put it at the end: like this

```
lookup= 'US'

result = original.replace(lookup,"") + " " + str(lookup)
```

> output: 3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360GREENSBORO27408-7611   NC US

However, what if I have lookup as a list like below:

```
lookup = ['US','CA','INDIA','CHINA']
```

and multiple input as a list like below:

```
input = ['3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 US NC','200 LINE AVE STE 360 GBORO 77611 CA NC','60 Indiranagar INDIA Bangalore']
```

I need to find the country for each input list and put it at the end of a string for each list.

I tried many methods but couldn't do. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you always want to swap the last two values?

Comment: NO,Only when you find the lookup values like US,or CA if not at the end we'll pust it at the back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by breaking the string down into tokens:

```
>>> address = '3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 US NC'
>>> tokens = address.split()
>>> tokens
['3200', 'NORTHLINE', 'AVE', 'STE', '360', 'GREENSBORO', '27408-7611', 'US', 'NC']
```

If you want to put a country code at the end you can sort the list of tokens using a `key` sort value. Example:

```
>>> sorted_tokens = sorted(tokens, key=lambda token: token == "US")
>>> sorted_tokens
['3200', 'NORTHLINE', 'AVE', 'STE', '360', 'GREENSBORO', '27408-7611', 'NC', 'US']
```

To put this back into a string you can use a join

```
>>> sorted_address = ' '.join(sorted_tokens)
>>> sorted_address
3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 NC US
```

To make this work for a variety of country codes, you only need to slightly modify the `key`

```
lookup = ['US','CA','INDIA','CHINA']
sorted_tokens = sorted(tokens, key=lambda token: token in lookup)
```

Putting this altogether:

```
lookup = ['US','CA','INDIA','CHINA']
adresses = [
    '3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 US NC',
    '200 LINE AVE STE 360 GBORO 77611 CA NC',
    '60 Indiranagar INDIA Bangalore',
]


def sort_address(address):
    tokens = address.split()
    sorted_tokens = sorted(tokens, key=lambda token: token in lookup)
    return ' '.join(sorted_tokens)


for address in adresses:
    print(sort_address(address))
```

```
3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 NC US
200 LINE AVE STE 360 GBORO 77611 NC CA
60 Indiranagar Bangalore INDIA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex alternation approach as follows:

```py
lookup = ['US', 'CA', 'INDIA', 'CHINA']
regex = r'\s+(' + r'|'.join(lookup) + r')(.*)'
df["address"] = df["address"].str.replace(regex, r'\2 \1', regex=True)
```

Assuming you are using a regular Python list, rather than a data frame, we can try a similar approach:

```py
lookup = ['US', 'CA', 'INDIA', 'CHINA']
regex = r'\s+(' + r'|'.join(lookup) + r')(.*)'
inp = ['3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 US NC','200 LINE AVE STE 360 GBORO 77611 CA NC','60 Indiranagar INDIA Bangalore']
output = [re.sub(regex, r'\2 \1', x) for x in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['3200 NORTHLINE AVE STE 360 GREENSBORO 27408-7611 NC US',
 '200 LINE AVE STE 360 GBORO 77611 NC CA',
 '60 Indiranagar Bangalore INDIA']
```